# Sort a text file according to a character within a field

Tags: text-processing, sort

I have a file named : `newfile` which consist of the following data

```
1 AC BB CC
2 AB CC DD
3 CA BB CC
4 BE DD EE
5 BD AA AA
```

I type the following command in bash to sort the data according to the second character, second field

> sort -k3 newfile

I expected the following results

```
3 CA BB CC
2 AB CC DD
1 AC BB CC
5 BD AA AA
4 BE DD EE
```

why am i getting the following results and how am i suppose to solve according to the third character (ignoring the blank)

```
5 BD AA AA
1 AC BB CC
3 CA BB CC
2 AB CC DD
4 BE DD EE
```

Comment: What is your definition of _third field_?

Comment: Your expected result doesn't seem to be _sorted_ by any field.

Comment: A field is not a single letter! By default, it's a block of characters separated by blank characters.

Comment: It seems he want to sort by the second char of second column.

Comment: @Gnouc yea i want to sort the second char of second column

Comment: why does it sort according to the second column , first field when i type -k2 instead of -k3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To sort on a specific character within a field (i.e. a block of character surrounded by blank characters). You can use this specific syntax :

```
sort -k 1.4 file
```

This will sort on the fourth character of the file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383706/unix-sort-on-column-without-separator for details.

If you experience counterintuitive results while playing with `-k`, add the option `-b`. This will make `sort` ignore the blanks. So

```
sort -b -k 2.2 file
```

gives what you want : second character of second field, ignoring blanks.

Comment: Vote up! I didn't know about extended keydef in sort.

Comment: why does it sort according to the second column , first field when i type -k2 instead of -k3

Comment: @Computernerd The first character of the -k option is the field number. The second one is the position inside the field. By default, it's 1. Hence, -k2 is equivalent to -k2.1 : first character of second field.

Comment: Only 6 upvotes!? This answer is incredible!

Answer (score 2):

Third field means third field when separated by spaces (standard shell word splitting). This is exactly what you got and what anyone would expect from this feature (people usually sort tables, with arbitrarily long words or numbers in the fields, this is actually the first time I've seen sorting by single characters).
If you want to sort by a character column you need to split it to characters, sort, and squeeze back. If these are spaces, we can put additional tabs in between with `sed`, sort, and remove the tabs:

```
cat "newfile" | sed 's/./&\t/g' | sort -k3 | tr -d '\t'
```

You could also provide the filename to `sed` directly, but I usually do it with a pipe because I may have to receive the input from another script anyway.

If you already have spaces AND tabs in your file, you will have to be more creative to avoid deleting original whitespace too.